# How do I send data to my PHP script using AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm new to PHP and Javascript/Ajax so please bear with me.

All I need to do is get a variable from Ajax and set it as a variable in php. I'm trying to do this with a super global `GET` but something is not right. I don't want to this by submitting the form.

Here's my JS:

```
function myFunction(){
var hora= document.getElementById("hora").value;
$.ajax({ 
        type : 'GET',
         url : 'reservation.php',
         data : {hora: hora},
         success : function(data) {
                console.log(hora);//This is because I was curious as to
                             // what the console would say. I found
                             // that this sets the super global if I
                             // change the url to something else that
                             // doesn't exist. Console would say
                             // -GET http://localhost/bus/(somepage).php?hora=4
                             // 404 (Not Found)-  
                alert(hora);
               }
})
}
```

Here's my PHP:

```
Hora:
 <select name="hora" id="hora" onchange="myFunction()">
     <?php
         $query = "SELECT * FROM vans";
         $horas_result = mysql_query($query);
         while ($horas = mysql_fetch_array($horas_result)) {
        echo "<option value=\"{$horas["van_id"]}\">{$horas["time"]}</option>";
         }
    ?>
 </select>&nbsp;
 Asientos Disponibles:
    <?php echo $_GET["hora"]; ?>
        //Right now I only want to echo this variable..
```

As you can see, right now I only want to echo this variable, later on I'll be using this to write a query.

Comment: The HTML in your php file will not be rendered. 
reservation.php has to be a pure php file, it is only used to process the information that the variable contains. It's not supposed to be viewable by the user.

Comment: @AlanChavez: The result of the PHP will be sent to the AJAX call.  It *can* be HTML if he wants.

Comment: @RocketHazmat My bad, that's true. The file doesn't have to be pure php.

Comment: So, what's the problem here?  A 404 error?

Comment: No, I just did that out of curiosity. I just want to put a value into a super global 'get' with ajax and retrive it with php..If the above code is not correct, please help me out with a different code.

Comment: have you just tried making your php file `<?php echo $_GET["hora"]; ?>` and I think you want `alert(data)` in your AJAX, right?

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the code i post, ajax is used to post/get data without need to refresh the page but if you just want to post the data and give the result in other page use a form instead.

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET["hora"]))
    {
        echo $_GET["hora"];

        exit;
    }
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Page title</title>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#hora").change(function ()
                    {
                        $.ajax(
                            { 
                                type : 'GET',
                                url : '',
                                data : $('select[name=\'hora\']'),
                                success : function(data)
                                    {
                                        $('#ajax_result').html('Asientos Disponibles:  ' + data);
                                    },
                                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                                    {
                                        alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                                    }
                            }
                        )
                    }
                )

            }
        )

</script>

<select name="hora" id="hora">
     <?php
         $query = "SELECT * FROM vans";
         $horas_result = mysql_query($query);
         while ($horas = mysql_fetch_array($horas_result)) {
        echo "<option value=\"{$horas["van_id"]}\">{$horas["time"]}</option>";
         }
    ?>
 </select>&nbsp;
    <div id="ajax_result">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OK, finally got it working. But I want to set this as a variable so I can use with php. Is this possible?

Comment: @user2145828 at the begining of the code you have the php code related to the GET action so there you can insert the code you need, for example use the variable hora to search the database and output whatever you want, for example the left seats.

Answer (score 0):

For example, the following script

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: {value:1}
        }).done(function(msg) {
                    // msg contains whatever value test.php echoes. Whether it is code, or just raw data. 
            if(msg=="Success") { 
              alert("hello world"); 
              } else {
                alert("Hello Hell")
            }
        });
```

Will set the variable `$_POST['value']` to `1`

and my test.php looks like:

```
<?php
 if($_POST['value'] == "1") {
     echo "Success";
 } else {
     echo "Failure";
 }
?>
```

If you run that example, the webpage will show you an alert box with the text "Hello World"
If you change the value to any other number, it will show you an alert with the text "Hello Hell"

Hope that answers your question.